# Java Crypto AES inserting foreign byte into output

Tags: java, cryptography

I'm trying to stream a Portable Executable binary over HTTP encrypted.  To accomplish this, I am using Java Crypto AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding.

The issue is that the output is adding a foreign byte 0x0D at position 134 of the output byte array.  On disk, the file looks like:

```
... 0x65 0x2E 0x0D 0x0D 0x0A 0x24 ...
```

However, after being decrypted, the result is:

```
... 0x65 0x2E 0x0D 0x0D 0x0D 0x0A 0x24 ...
```

As you can see, a foreign byte is being introduced.  The ASCII value for this hex digit is carriage return which makes me particularly suspicious.

This issue occurs on all types of files, including a test JPEG as shown:

```
... 0x09 0x08 0x0A 0x0C ...
```

Whereas the output is

```
... 0x09 0x08 0x0D 0x0A 0x0C ...
```

**Strangely, this foreign 0x0D seems to precede the first 0x0A**.

Here is my encryption method:

```
private String encrypt(String message) {
    SecretKey outKey = // key from session
    byte[] iv = // iv from session
    Cipher outCipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding")
    outCipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, outKey, new IvParameterSpec(iv))
    return Hex.encodeToString(outCipher.doFinal(message.bytes)).trim()
}
```

I am using the Apache Shiro hex encoding utility class.

Comment: Have you checked whether the hex lib is the culprit by trying to hexlify those suspicious bytes?

Comment: Is your output sent as bytes or as text.  At first glance, this looks like a newline inserted automatically into a text stream.  Try switching the output to bytes, or to Base64 text and see what happens.

Comment: This issue is not because of the encryption code and it is very unlikely that it is an issue with the hex encoder. This is character I/O related. Please show more of the process or we cannot answer...